# Two Overlapping Nonograms

Tags: visual, nonogram

Find the 5-letter word made by the overlapping nonograms.

> [image: Some description provided.]

Comment: I know the puzzle is now over, but, generally, I suggest that you (i.e. anyone who uses this idea) keep the two nonograms separate so that the digits are clearer and we don't have to determine which color represent the overlapping part of two digits (it's easy, but, IMO, unnecessary hassle).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 5-letter word is

> PAINT

Cyan nonogram:

> [image]

Red nonogram:

> [image]

Both overlapping:

> [image]
>
>  The black squares spell the letters "Paint", which is the final answer.

Comment: Managed to solve the nonograms but could not get the word. Nice, +1.